# postfix error connection

Tags: postfix, localhost, telnet

my postfix not connect in the lan just localhost and local ip address:

**In the postfix server:**

:/etc/postfix$ telnet 172.28.204.36 25

Trying 172.28.204.36...

Connected to 172.28.204.36.

Escape character is '^]'.

220 xxx.xxx.xxx ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)

**From a windows client:**

C:\Users\Administrator>telnet 172.28.204.36 25
Connecting To 172.28.204.36...Could not open connection to the host, on port 25:
Connect failed

**:/etc/postfix$ postconf -n**

alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases

append_dot_mydomain = no

biff = no

compatibility_level = 2

inet_interfaces = all

inet_protocols = all

mailbox_size_limit = 0

mydestination =

myhostname = xxx.xxx.xxx

mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 172.28.204.0/24 172.29.2.0/24

myorigin = /etc/mailname

readme_directory = no

recipient_delimiter = +

smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)

smtpd_command_filter = pcre:/etc/postfix/command_filter

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination

smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem

smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache

smtpd_use_tls = yes

**Master.cf**

smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd

smtpd      pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd

submission inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd

**:/etc/postfix$ sudo ufw status**

Status: inactive

**:/etc/postfix$ sudo ufw app list**

Available applications:

Apache

Apache Full

Apache Secure

OpenSSH

Postfix

Postfix SMTPS

Postfix Submission

**:/etc/postfix$ getenforce**

Disabled

**:/etc/postfix$ lsb_release -a**

No LSB modules are available.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS

Release:        16.04

Codename:       xenial

¿I have a wrong configurarion?
Thanks

**tcpdump**

:/var/log$ sudo tcpdump -vv port 25 tcpdump:

listening on ens160,    link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
16:19:04.022139 IP (tos 0x2,ECT(0), ttl 128, id 17267, offset 0,    flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)

172.28.204.32.24686 > zabbix.zabbix.lan.smtp: Flags [SEW], cksum 0xd830 (correct), seq 2750578983, win 8192, options [mss    1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0 16:19:07.014510 IP (tos    0x2,ECT(0), ttl 128, id 17282, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6),    length 52)

172.28.204.32.24686 > zabbix.zabbix.lan.smtp: Flags [SEW], cksum 0xd830 (correct), seq 2750578983, win 8192, options [mss    1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0 16:19:13.030200 IP (tos    0x0, ttl 128, id 17304, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length    48)

172.28.204.32.24686 > zabbix.zabbix.lan.smtp: Flags [S], cksum 0xecff (correct), seq 2750578983, win 8192, options [mss    1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0

Comment: could you add the relevent postfix log corresponding to the windows connection attempt here?

Comment: The syslog no register in the tail:

Mar 11 16:15:08 zabbix kernel: [1812799.055559] mail connectionIN= OUT=ens160 SRC=172.28.204.36 DST=104.47.74.10 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=64501 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=53890 DPT=25 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0

Comment: I meant entries in /var/log/mail.log ( postfix does not log in /var/log/syslog )
Also, check if you have firewall that block tcp on port 25 from your lan